# How to retrieve a page from a web-server using ESP8266 with the program running on Arduino instead of the ESP module?

Tags: esp8266

I have connected an ESP8266-01 module to an Arduino as in the following schematic with the RX and TX pins changed to pins 8 and 9 instead of 0 and 1:

[image]

I am using the ESP8266wifi library at the following link:

https://github.com/ekstrand/ESP8266wifi

I have looked at the ESP8266HTTPClient library but that is for the ESP8266 board. **I want my code to run on the Arduino Uno and not on the ESP8266!** I have written the following code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SerialESP8266wifi.h>

const String API_PASSWORD = "stn1234";

#define RX_PIN          8   // RX of Arduino (connected to TX of ESP8266)
#define TX_PIN          9   // TX of Arduino (connected to RX of ESP8266)
#define ESP_RESET_PIN   12 

#define SERVER_IP           "192.168.43.234"
#define SERVER_PORT         "80"
#define WIFI_SSID           "MyWIFI"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD       "myWifiPassword"

uint8_t wifi_started = false;

const char RST[] PROGMEM = "RST";
const char IDN[] PROGMEM = "*IDN?";

#define CHANGE_DELAY        5000


void initializeWifi();
void transmitData(String);
String getResponse();
void transmitStatus();

SoftwareSerial swSerial =  SoftwareSerial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN);
SerialESP8266wifi wifi(swSerial, swSerial, ESP_RESET_PIN, Serial);

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Initializing...");
    initializeWifi();
    Serial.println("Initialization complete");
}

void loop() 
{
    transmitStatus();
    Serial.print("Transmission complete, ");
    int s = (CHANGE_DELAY/1000);
    Serial.print(s);
    Serial.println("s until next cycle");
    delay(CHANGE_DELAY);
}

void transmitStatus()
{
    int a = (int)random(100);
    int b = (int)random(100);
    String url = "/LocalWebProject/api/testConnection.php?a=" + String(a) + "&b=" + String(b);

    transmitData(url);
    String response = getResponse();
    Serial.print("Reply received: ");
    Serial.println(response);
}

void initializeWifi()
{
    swSerial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Starting Wifi");
    wifi.setTransportToTCP();
    wifi.endSendWithNewline(false);     // Will end all transmissions with a newline and carrage return ie println.. default is true

    wifi_started = wifi.begin();
    if(wifi_started) 
    {
        Serial.println("Wifi started, connecting to AP...");
        wifi.connectToAP(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
        Serial.println("Connected to AP");
    } else {
        Serial.println("ESP module not working");
    }
}

void transmitData(String url)
{
    Serial.println("Connecting to server...");
    wifi.connectToServer(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);

    String data = String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
           "Host: " + wifi.getIP() + "\r\n" + 
           "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    Serial.println("Connected. Transmitting data...");
    wifi.send(SERVER, data);
}

String getResponse()
{
    while(1)
    {
        Serial.println("Waiting for response...");
        WifiMessage in = wifi.listenForIncomingMessage(6000);
        if(in.hasData) 
        {
            if(in.channel == SERVER)
            {
                Serial.print("Reply received from the server: ");
                Serial.println(in.message);             
                return in.message;
            }
        }

        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("Retrying, ");
    }
}
```

I have an Apache server running on Ubuntu 18.10 with a PHP project running on port 80. The testConnection.php page takes 2 GET parameters (integers) and returns the sum.

Problem:
It says that ESP module is not working. The AP in my case is a local hotspot on my mobile.

I have tried running the given example "SerialESP8266_library_test" and confusingly enough, it prints that it has successfully connected to my AP, but on my phone I do not see it connected. Only 1 device is visible as connected, which is my laptop which is running the Apache server and the web project. Also connectToAP returns 1, and connectToServer returns 0.

What am I doing wrong? I know that the ESP module requires power and the Arduino 3V3 is insufficient but I am just testing the code right now and I will do the required changes later on. Due to this, I am placing my Android phone just beside the ESP module so that it has no problems connecting to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT/blob/master/examples/Basic/WebClient/WebClient.ino

Comment: `swSerial.begin(115200)`. I don't think softwareSerial can even run that fast. The library you are using for wifi uses `9600` baud. I'd give that a try.

Comment: @Gerben Some modules are 9600, some are 115200 - it depends on the version of the firmware. SoftwareSerial can *run* at 115200, but it can't react fast enough to incoming bytes to reliably receive a stream of data.

Comment: @Juraj The WiFiEspAt requires flashing with AT 1.7, I did not want to do that

Comment: @Gerben I tried with 9600 and made some other changes. Now, it correctly connects to the AP (shows up on my phone), also connects to the server. But receives a HTTP 400 Bad request error. Is there any problem in the GET request format? My page is at:  http://192.168.43.234/LocalWebProject/api/testConnection.php

Comment: Host header value should be the name or IP of the server

Comment: @Juraj as per the examples, etc., the host is the local IP of the ESP module. Anyway, I tried your suggestion by providing the SERVER_IP there but still I get the same problem

Comment: the HTTP protocol is not defined by this example

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is working by setting baud rate to 9600 and shortening the GET URL. Maybe there is a length restriction in the library.